# Switch from soap11 to soap12

Tags: c#, soap

I switched the protocol that I'm using in C# from

```
oCode.SoapVersion = SoapProtocolVersion.Soap11;
```

to

```
oCode.SoapVersion = SoapProtocolVersion.Soap12;
```

I get an error "WSE005: The input was not a valid SOAP message because it has either the wrong name or the wrong namespace. The name specified follows: Envelope. The namespace it was defined under follows: http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope."

I can't find anything about what it means, there's nothing in Google with that message.  Are there other things I need to consider when switching from 11 to 12?  I didn't seem to find anyone else with the same issue.

Any help is welcome, thanks.

We're not using a WCF, but the

```
namespace System.Web.Services.Protocols
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class SoapHttpClientProtocol : HttpWebClientProtocol
    {
        public SoapHttpClientProtocol();

        [ComVisible(false)]
        [DefaultValue(SoapProtocolVersion.Default)]
        [WebServicesDescriptionAttribute("ClientProtocolSoapVersion")]
        public SoapProtocolVersion SoapVersion { get; set; }

        public void Discover();
        protected IAsyncResult BeginInvoke(string methodName, object[] parameters, AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState);
        protected object[] EndInvoke(IAsyncResult asyncResult);
        protected virtual XmlReader GetReaderForMessage(SoapClientMessage message, int bufferSize);
        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri);
        protected virtual XmlWriter GetWriterForMessage(SoapClientMessage message, int bufferSize);
        protected object[] Invoke(string methodName, object[] parameters);
        protected void InvokeAsync(string methodName, object[] parameters, SendOrPostCallback callback);
        protected void InvokeAsync(string methodName, object[] parameters, SendOrPostCallback callback, object userState);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

SOAP version 1.2 [made a number of breaking changes, including the namespace of the SOAP envelope](https://www.w3.org/TR/soap12-part1/#version).

You didn't specify whether it was the client or the server code you changed, but one or other of the sides of this communication are not aware of the version change — probably the server, which is responding that it doesn't recognise the SOAP 1.2 envelope. If it doesn't support SOAP 1.2, you can't use this option.

Comment: Ok, I'm only changing the client side.  The server is a partners server.